# Can't deploy Windows 8.1 application to Window 8 device

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I am working on Windows 8.1 application and i have a device with Windows 8 OS. It seems many 8.1 applications can install in Windows 8 device from the store with a warning that "It will work better with Windows 8.1' .It is showing some error with certification When i try to deploy my Windows 8.1 app to the Windows 8 device .
 So want to know that is it possible to install Windows 8.1 app in Windows 8 machine? 
 Must i upgrade the device OS to Window 8.1 before  deploying ? 
What i need to deploy Windows 8.1 application in Windows 8 device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 8.1 you can develop apps for two platform versions:

- Windows 8
- Windows 8.1

Apps targeted for Windows 8 will run in both, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1. Apps targeted for Windows 8.1 will only run in Windows 8.1

You can find the target platform version of your app by right clicking in the app project and then clicking in Application tab. There you will find the Target Platform Version.

When an app is published in the Windows Store, developers have the option to upload two packages, one for each platform version. It is almost sure that the Windows 8.1 version will be better than the Windows 8 version, since the APIs for 8.1 are better :)

Comment: Yes, you have to upgrade your Windows 8 device, or create a Windows 8 version of your app.